# Send an email to an address for php to read and create variables from it

Tags: php, smtp

The basic concept here is I want to create a contact form that would create a page (I already have that part) and allow that page to keep populating from back and forth email. Is there a way that I could have PHP occupy an email and pull variables from it?

**EDIT:** Running on Debian 8.1

Comment: Not really sure what you are trying to do, but maybe try saving it in a session, this way you can access it from any page, and if user returns to that contact page again his email will be there.

Comment: @muhammedm. I need a way to email php to do something similar to any email ticketing system

Comment: Use php's mail() function to send emails , explain more if u eed more help.

Comment: @muhammedm.    I do not need to send email through php, I need to receive emails for example I send an email to php(this is what I cant figure out right now) and in that email is a small message php would take that message and then insert it into a database

Comment: You need email piping. Thats whats it is called. if you are runnix a *nix box its simple. Here is how to do it using cpanel https://www.siteground.com/kb/how_to_pipe_an_email_to_a_php_script/